# Symfony 3, форма из двух Entity классов

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

Здравствуйте! Есть два класса Entity, которые содержат разные поля. мне нужно сделать общую форма и потом соответственно записать данные в из формы в БД.
Примерно так сформировать форму и снизу добавить поля из другого класса.

```
$builder->add('fname')
        ->add('username')
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class)
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно.

```
$builder->add('fname')
    ->add('username')
    ->add('password', PasswordType::class)
     //Добавляем новое поля 
    ->add(croup, EntityType::class,array(
     //Указываем класс
     'class' => 'AppBundle:Group
     'choice_label' => 'Group') );
```